# import com.android.widget.SlidingPaneLayout not found

Tags: java, android

I want to use ((SlidingPaneLayout) getParent()).isSecondChildUnder((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY()) but didn't resolve this method. Did it removed in newer version? If anyone knows that it was in older version, please mention the version and how could I use this method?

```
import com.android.widget.SlidingPaneLayout;

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        if (((SlidingPaneLayout) getParent()).isSecondChildUnder((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY())) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout) it was added in 22.1.0.  The documentation doesn't mention that is has been removed.  However, the documentation gives the fully qualified name as:

```
  android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
```

which doesn't match your import statement.